# Java - 2 Way 'Has A' Relationship

Tags: java, oop, object, object-oriented-analysis

I have just started a project to make my employer a management software. I have a niggling, but potentially simple, query that I can't seem to find any information on.

Is it prudent/good practice to have a 2 way 'has a' relationship between objects. So can, for example, a `Client` object 'have a' `Site`, and then the `Site` 'has a' `Client`, where the `Client` object is the `Client` that 'has' the `Site`?

```
public class Client {
    Site site;
}

public class Site {
    Client client;
}
```

Is there anything objectionable (no pun intended) to this, or is it fine? I am currently creating a mock-up UML for the project, and this has been bothering me.

Comment: Great question, this always bothers me too.

Comment: Totally normal. Think of parent/child relationships. Sometimes it is necessary for children to have access to the parents and vice versa.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you can run into data integrity issues if you're not careful: `bob.site = a; a.client = joe;`

Comment: @damo That should be fine. I'll be putting a lot of effort into loose coupling on this project, simply because of the complexity.

Comment: the mediator design pattern.   Up front way to say this'll mess with your head.   _Sometimes_, right next to the jumble about the mediator pattern is a solution, which, if you follow it _**exactly**_ will help you use these two objects with needing a personal stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything objectionable to this, or is it fine?

There's no definitive answer to this. The best answer is: it depends to the design of your application.

**When to use it**

If your `Client` object should navigate to the `Site` object and your `Site` object should navigate to the `Client` object, then the current example in your code is fine. Still, probably you will need some way to associate these elements, probably by an additional id field on one of the classes or in both.

If it happens that you work with a framework that helps you to bind the classes automatically like Hibernate, then maintaining the circular reference won't be a problem for you.

**When not to use it**

Basically, for text serialization, since it will generate an infinite loop. As already mentioned in [Raibaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149143/1065197), a library like Jackson will fall into infinite loop while serializing `Client` or `Site` class into a JSON string<sup>1</sup>. Note that this is also valid when serializing to other `String` data like passing the objects through a JAX-WS web service in XML (more info: [What happens to generic class in jax-ws webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12908112/1065197)).

<sup>1</sup> This can be solved using annotations (`@Something`) that belong to a specific library e.g. `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` from [Jackson library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), as noted by @SimonAndréForsberg, but the downside of this solution is that your classes will have tight coupling with the library.

Comment: With a somehow updated version of Jackson there are many possible ways to avoid an infinite loop in situations like this, either by using `@JsonManagedReference` in combination with `@JsonBackReference` or by using the lovely `@JsonIdentityInfo`. I have been using these solutions a lot lately and they work perfectly with Jackson.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg the downside of this approach is that your classes have tight coupling with Jackson. Not everything good in programming life is free =\

Comment: Sure, you do have a point there. But since Jackson is so awesome I'm not so frightened of coupling my classes with it :) (I know, I might regret having said that)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg that's a design decision to take and will depend on each project. In my case, I would prefer to avoid them as much as possible at least that it is proven I can replace them easily like Spring and EJB/CDI annotations.

Comment: I am not sure what the Spring+EJB/CDI annotations are (please enlighten me! I have used Spring but not sure what you're talking about still). However, I just discovered that in Jackson it is possible to [decouple the classes from Jackson entirely using mix-in annotations](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html). Decoupling solved :)

Answer (score 2):

It's common to have a mutual *association* between objects.

For example, in some user interface toolkits, a visual component will have references to its children, and each child may have a reference to its parent.

The term *has-a* is frequently used to communicate ownership of one object by another. When this is true, the relationship is usually one-way.

One good definition of these terms is provided in *"The Unified Modeling Language User Guide"*, by Booch, Rumbaugh and Jacobson:

> Aggregation -- A plain association between two classes represents a structual relationship between peers, meaning that both classes are conceptually at the same level, no one more important than the other. Sometimes, you will want to model a "whole/part" relationship, in which one class represents a larger thing (the "whole"), which consists of smaller things (the "parts"). This kind of relationship is called aggregation, which represents a "has-a" relationship, meaning that an object of the whole has objects of the part.

Answer (score 2):

It is common, but I would consider how loosely coupled you want the child object to be from its parent. If you have the reference to the parent from the child object then you will not be able to reuse the object with another parent / no parent.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite normal and quite common to have a bidirectional association like the one in your example.

The only caveat you may want to consider is when you are going to serialize your objects, for instance in json using Jackson or any other library, you should exclude one of the two sides of the association from serializing to avoid ending in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't thought of that. Nice to have potential pitfalls brought to my attention. :)

Comment: @RudiKershaw Some serialization frameworks and APIs have workarounds for that, like using identifiers instead of serializing the whole object graph every time.

Comment: The comment above is correct, and in particular Jackson, the JSON framework i mentioned, has annotations to exclude fields from serialization.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis again, this depends on the design. Probably at some cases you just need to serialize the data of one of the classes, and for other cases you need to send the whole object with it's relationships. E.g. display the `Site` data in a drop down list and in a table next to the client info.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Right. I was thinking of something like [`@JsonIdentityInfo`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) in Jackson that removes the infinite reference loop during its serialization.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis with my last example, I also tried to say: you don't always need to serialize all the object fields even if the framework *handles* this for you (in case of a drop down list, you only need 2 fields, nothing more), but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Using Jackson, it is entirely possible to both [avoid the infinite loop](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) and avoid [extra coupling with Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html), which is why I'm downvoting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to stick to 1-way relationship whenever possible. 2-way relationships makes two classes tied together and a change in one of them causes the other to change two. Ask yourself if such relation is really natural...

If you have to, just make sure both are interfaces or at least one of them is.

Comment: "a change in one of them causes the other to change too"? How? Why? Can you provide an example of this? I have to disagree with you here. 2-way relationships are perfectly normal IMO (consider a XML-tree structure for example where parents knows about their childs and childs knows about their parents).

Comment: XML has nothing to do with Java. If both objects have reference to each other this usually means they use each other interfaces extensively. This means that a change in one of them causes the need to change the other too. Of course you can always prevent it by making this interface at least stable.

Comment: The XML-tree structure was an example. There are a multitude of structures where childs and parents are connected. I still don't understand (or agree) with "a change in one of them causes the need to change the other too". Are you talking about the interfaces themselves? In that case I don't think it's relevant to the question. Are you talking about the object references in these objects? In that case I think that normally when you use this 2-way relationship you don't change just one of the connections like that.

Comment: Looks like you've answered your own question in your last statement. Let me quote: "When you use this 2-way relationship you don't change just one of the connections like that" - and it's all I meant. You should have this in mind when creating such constructs. But yes, it is perfectly normal, let me be clear.